# Weird Segmantation fault on writing a to a file c

Tags: c, file

In this case of the project that am working on , am receiving a message and i want to send a response by writing a message to the file descriptor.But the problem is that the write function returns Segmentation Fault and i dont know why. For example i receive a message  going to the right case and send response by writing to a file when i use write it shows that the message went to the destination but after that returns segmentation fault.If instead of write use a printf it works and doesnt show segmentation fault .Can any one help me with that ?

```
typedef enum operation{
    insert,
    read_reg,
    info,
    error
}Operation;
typedef struct request{
    Operation operation;
    int ID;
    int counter;
}Request; 

int **regs;

fd=open(port,O_RDWR|O_NOCTTY);
        
        if(fd==-1){
            perror(port);
            
            exit(1);
        }
regs=(int **)malloc(2*sizeof(int*));
        if(regs==NULL){
            printf("Cant create data base for registers\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        
        for(int i=1;i<=2;i++){
            regs[i]=(int*)malloc(SIZE*sizeof(int));
            if(regs[i]==NULL){
                exit(1);
            }
        }
        
        regs[1][0]=1;
        regs[2][0]=3;
char str[12];
char buffer[255];
    while(1){
    
        //Clean buffer
    memset(buffer,0,SIZE);
    FD_ZERO(&readfd);
    FD_SET(fd,&readfd);
    timeout.tv_sec=100;
    timeout.tv_usec=0;
        
    status=select(40,&readfd,NULL,NULL,&timeout);
        
    if(status==0){  
        printf("Cannot receive data from client\n");
        printf("\tTime Out\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    read_num=read(fd,buffer,sizeof(buffer));
    if(read_num<0) perror("Error in reading file descriptor\n");
    if(read_num>0){
        //while(1){
            fl.l_type   = F_RDLCK;  /* read lock */
            fl.l_whence = SEEK_SET; /* beginning of file */
            fl.l_start  = 0;        /* offset from l_whence */
            fl.l_len    = 0;        /* length, 0 = to EOF */
            fl.l_pid    = getpid(); /* PID */
            fcntl(fd, F_SETLKW, &fl); 
            request=parse_request(buffer);  
            if(request){
                switch(request->operation){
                    case info:
                        write(fd,"OK\n",1);
                        break;
                        
                    case read_reg:
                        write(fd,"OK\n",1);
                        printf("prepei na diabaso reg\n");
                        break;
                    case insert:
                        printf("edo vazo timi\n");
                        write(fd,"OK\n",1);
                        break;
                    case error:
                        printf("prepei na petakso error\n");
                        write(fd,"OK\n",1);
                        break;
                
                }
                printf("prepei na me deis meta apo kathe break\n");
            }
            printf("kai edw prepei na me deis \n");
            fl.l_type   = F_UNLCK;
            fcntl(fd, F_SETLK, &fl); // unset lock 
        //}
    }
    printf("edw ?\n");
}
```

parse_request is a function that splits the message and determines information about it.

```
Request  *parse_request(char *buffer){

    char *token=NULL,*value=NULL;
    Request *rep=NULL;
    char string_split[4];
    int i=0;
    

    rep=(Request*)malloc(sizeof(Request));
    rep->counter=0;
    
    token=strtok(buffer,"=");
    //extract  value 
    value=strtok(NULL,"=");

    token=strtok(token,"+");
    //extract register
    token=strtok(NULL,"+");
    
    //Set up registers ID 
    rep->ID=atoi(&token[strlen(token)-1]);
    //Set up operation type
    
    if(!value){
        rep->operation=read_reg;    
            //printf("Operation :read\n");
    }else{
        if(strcmp(value,"?")==0){
            rep->operation=info;
            //printf("Operation :info\n");
        }else{
            //check if number is valid
            if(isValid(value,rep)==1){
                rep->operation=insert;
                //printf("Operation :insert\n");
                //printf("am gonna insert value:%d\n",atoi(value));
                regs[rep->ID][rep->counter++]=atoi(value);
                printf("%d\n",regs[rep->ID][rep->counter++]=atoi(value));
            }else{
                rep->operation=error;
                //printf("Operation :error\n");
            }
        }
        
    }
        
    
    
    return rep;

}
```

Comment: `write(fd,"OK\n",1);` writes just one character to fd.

Comment: @user3121023 regs[2]  is a 2d array where reg1 is at regs[1][...] and reg2[2][...] lets say that it is the problem ok why on a simple write(fd,"OK",2) returns segmentation fault ?

Comment: @stark yeah i know this is not my problem the problem is that after writing something it returns segmentation fault

Comment: OT: `regs=(int **)malloc(2*sizeof(int*));` : dynamically allocating a fixed size of memory is rather pointless, why not simply declare `int *regs[2];` and drop `malloc` and `free` (if any) alltogether?

Comment: @Jabberwocky ok i'll do that , this is not my problem though

Comment: regarding: `for(int i=1;i<=2;i++){`  in C, indexes into arrays start with 0, not 1.  The list of valid indexes is 0...(number of elements in array -1 )

Comment: @tsoki I know, that's why I wrote "OT" meaning "off topic". You'll find this kind of comments often here

Comment: regarding: `status=select(40,&readfd,NULL,NULL,&timeout);`  are you sure that your OS will allow 40 files to be open at the same time?  much better to use: `status=select( fd+1,&readfd,NULL,NULL,&timeout);`

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  Please post a [mcve] so we can recreate the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: OT: regarding statements like: `rep=(Request*)malloc(sizeof(Request));`  in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code (and is error prone)

Comment: OT: regarding: `token=strtok(buffer,"=");
    //extract  value 
    value=strtok(NULL,"=");`  are you expecting that `buffer[]` will contain a second `=` character?  Please post a typical buffer contents

Comment: regarding: `char buffer[255]; ... memset(buffer,0,SIZE);`  if `SIZE` is not 255 then this is a problem.  Suggest: `memset( buffer, 0, sizeof( buffer ) );`

Comment: @user3629249  buffer always has messages like AT+<REG>=<VALUE> , i used memset like you said but still the same , btw thank you very match for staying here and helping me with my problem

Comment: @user3629249 i have found the problem , it is at the parse_request function where i set up my ID :  rep->ID=atoi(&token[strlen(toke)-1]); but why ?

Comment: Please re-read the MAN page for the function: strtok() note especially how the found delimiter is replaced via a NUL byte. Then consider the places in the code where you call strtok() more than once with the same delimiter

Answer (score 0):

regarding a buffer that contains:

```
AT+<REG>=<VALUE>
```

the first call to `strtok()` replaces the `+` with a NUL byte.

A second call to `strtok()` does not find a `+` in the buffer, so continues to search through memory until some 'random' `+` is encountered.

Now you have a pointer `token` pointing to memory that your program should not access.

Then the program tries to output the memory at that 'invalid' 'token' pointer.  The result is a seq fault event.